# login to magento 1.7 from drupal 7

Tags: users

```
function custom_user_login($edit, $account) {

  require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/mage1/app/Mage.php";
  global $user;

  umask(0);
  Mage::App('default');
  $session = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session', array('name' => 'frontend'));
  try {
    $session->login('alvaro@test.com', 'cec123');

    $session->setCustomerAsLoggedIn($session->getCustomer());
  } catch (Exception $e) {
    print_r($e);
    exit;
  }
```

i am using this set of code from my D7 installation to log-in to magento.But it is not loggin into either D7 or magento.

But when i run this code from a seperate simple php file outside it logs in to magento successfully. what could be the problem.

Comment: can anybody suggest how to view the session and cookie info after a user is logged in

Comment: You've closed the `try` block with curly brace `}`, also the catch block; but you didn't close the function.

Comment: @indrock: it was mistake when i copied it here. in code it is properly closed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used Rules module to set a rule and redirect after that event occurs.

Its not fully error proof. But it works. It logs into both Drupal and Magento

I will update this if i find some errors once i dig deep.

For the time being its fine

Answer (score 0):

The function signature is not right, which may be the reason for the code not executing.
See [the docs for `hook_user_login`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user.api.php/function/hook_user_login/7) function.

The parameter `$edit` is passed by reference and not directly by value. So, the correct definition your function should be,

```
function custom_user_login(&$edit, $account) {

  // rest of the code goes here (not duplicating).

}
```

Also make sure, your modules name is `custom` and it has files `custom.info` and `custom.module` in the module directory. And offcourse, enable the module ;-)

Also, to suggest you to look into the session and cookie info (based on your comment), you can put an `echo '<pre>';print_r($_COOKIE); echo </pre>` inside your theme's `template.php` file.
Or simply install the [Devel](http://drupal.org/project/devel) module, and enter `dpm($_COOKIE);` inside your `template.php`, to see a nicely formatted result. You'll need to clear the cache to again load the fresh template files.
Similarly, you can print the `$_SESSION` superglobal to see the session information.

Comment: I made the $edit pass by reference, but still the output is same. not loggin into both D7 or magento. but am sure its loggin into D7 since it is entering the hook_user_login.I believe it is loggin out at some point. any insights from anybody

Comment: i tried to print the $_SESSION before and after login as u mentioned. but it returns an empty array.Cookie array i have added to your answer. plz see it.